# Moving A JLabel around with left key?

Tags: java, key, jlabel

I've been trying even with help I can't seem to move my JLabel around pressing the left arrow key. I have tried numerous ways, and still no progress. What am I doing wrong? I have set the code to when pressing the left key (it's supposed to anyways) decrease the X Variable by one moving the Label to the left, and instead it stays in place.

```
    package com.game.user;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    static int x = 474;
    static int y = 202;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("game");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(700, 700, 700, 700);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\sword.png"));
        label.setBounds(x, y, 24, 24);
        label.setVisible(true);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.add(label);
    /*  Keyboard key = new Keyboard();
            addKeyListener(key);
        */label.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                x--;
            }



            }
            });

            /*String keyString;
        if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            keyString = "key character = '" + c + "'";
            System.out.print("hello");
        } else {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            keyString = "key code = " + keyCode+ " ("+ KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode)+ ")";
        }
            }
        });

    }

    private static void addKeyListener(Keyboard key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/

    }}
```

Comment: have you tried `label.setBounds(--x, y, 24, 24)`?

Comment: The problem is focus

Answer (score 0):

Focus is the problem. As events (keyPressed) will only be fired if the object is focusable AND has focus. Your JLabel does not have focus, thus the keyevents will not be fired.

To Fix use  the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API

Here is an example.

```
this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "right");
this.getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //increment X as it is moving Right
    }
});
```

Then call...

```
lbl.revalidate();
```

to update the Jlabel after the new x-y values have been set.

Here is the perfect link to see how focus affects how your key presses work in swing

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076720/core-java/focus-on-swing.html

Comment: @Andymc hope this helps